# Is it possible to get items which are after specific one?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my db I have items. For example I have `59117b14d3c6295d5cd12262` id which is 10 item from the list. Is it possible somehow to get all items which is after `59117b14d3c6295d5cd12262` ?

[image: list of items]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can perform a **`$gt`** operation on `_id` field like this :

```
db.cars.find({_id: {$gt: ObjectId("59117b14d3c6295d5cd12262")}})
```

this will return all document with a greater `_id` than `59117b14d3c6295d5cd12262`

Answer (score 1):

If you already know that document is the 10th, then you can use [skip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/):

```
db.collection.find().skip(10);
```

Otherwise, you can use the [greater than operator ($gt)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/) to filter on `_id`:

```
db.collection.find({ _id: { $gt: ObjectId("59117b14d3c6295d5cd12262") }});
```

However, keep in mind that ordering by `ObjectId` will not always match the insertion order. From the [BSON Types documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid):

> The relationship between the order of `ObjectId` values and generation time is not strict within a single second. If multiple systems, or multiple processes or threads on a single system generate values, within a single second; `ObjectId` values do not represent a strict insertion order. Clock skew between clients can also result in non-strict ordering even for values because client drivers generate `ObjectId` values.